# Unpack a tuple with a single element or return None if tuple is None

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using python 2.7, I have the following code:

```
if result != None:
    (data,) = result
    return data

return None
```

The `result` variable is returned from a sqlite3 query that returns only one value. If the query returns a result, I want to unpack and return the data, otherwise I want to return None. The code above seems overly verbose and not at all pythonic. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can get rid of these useless `;` that are not pythonic either :-)

Comment: Part of the "unpythonic-ness" is the semicolons at the ends of the lines...

Comment: I'm a barbie girl living in a C/C# world. Semicolons removed, haha.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a `if` `else` condition:

```
return result[0] if result is not None else None
```

or simplify this down to:

```
return result[0] if result else None
```

if you don't care about `result` possibly being some other [false-y value](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) such as an empty tuple and such.

Comment: I'd just write `result[0] if result else None`, should work the same in the context.

Comment: I would use this (+1), but it might be worth noting that the OP's code will fail if the tuple has *more* than 1 element whereas this will happily pass.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could reference tuple values by index. Guess that's my python noobness showing. Thanks!

Comment: `result` evaluates to `False` not only in the case when it's `None`, but also when it's empty list or tuple. I would stick with `return None if  result is None else result[0]`.

Comment: @ovgolovin -- But that will raise an `IndexError` for an empty sequence.  I would think that returning `None` there is acceptable (maybe even desireable) although OP hasn't really said.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you'll only get either non-empty tuple or None, the simplest way:

```
return result and result[0]
```

Comment: I think you mean *shortest* way -- Not necessarily simplest.

Answer (score 2):

A way could be:

```
if result is not None:
    return result[0]
return None
```

There is also a more compact way to do this:

```
return (result or [None])[0]
```

but the first is more clear.

**Please** avoid using semicolon at the end (is not C code), and reading python documentation helps you. It's a well-spent time.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose no answer is complete without `try/except`:

```
try:
   return result[0]
except TypeError,IndexError:
   return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `;` that you left and the fact that `result != None` should be replaced by `result is not None`, I have no issues with your code.

It's simple, quite understandable, and won't silently fail you if one of these days your request returns 2 elements or more: it will raise an exception instead of silently returning the first element, like all the solutions so far.